# CQWP rating control not working

Tags: content-query-web-part, rating

I have got CQWP to display the rating control for items in a video library. I used fldtypes_Ratings.xsl to call the template in my custom Itemstyle.xsl. I managed to show the starts but its not interactive, and can't click on stars.

How do I get the rating control to work on CQWP?

Answer (score 1):

### Rendering Ratings in List View

SharePoint 2010 comes with the following fields for Social Ratings:

- AverageRating
- RatingCount

`fldtypes_ratings.xsl` is used for rendering `AverageRating` field in List View.

### Rendering Ratings in CQWP

Templates from file `fldtypes_ratings.xsl` could be utilized in CQWP , but in order to make it work properly, **some modifications** should be applied and here is how:

1. Prepare Ratings XSL stylesheet for CQWP

   [RatingsStyle.xsl](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/5671003)
2. In order to configure CQWP  for displaying Social Ratings , the
   following steps should be accomplished:

   - upload XSL stylesheets [RatingsStyle.xsl](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/5671003), [ItemStyle_Ratings.xsl](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/5673267) and     [ContentQueryMain_Ratings.xsl](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/5673418)
     into Style Library
   - specify [MainXslLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.cmsdataformwebpart.mainxsllink.aspx), [ItemXslLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.cmsdataformwebpart.itemxsllink.aspx) and [ParamaterBindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms458242) web part    properties

Figure 1. CQWP with Ratings

[image]

---

For more details please follow blog post [How to to retrieve and display Social Ratings in Content Query web part](http://blog.vgrem.com/2013/05/30/how-to-to-retrieve-and-display-social-ratings-in-content-query-web-part/)

Comment: how can i filter ratingcount only in last week? or last month. for detect trends... and best and attractive in last week? or month?